# How do i fail my testcase with testNG assertion?

Tags: selenium

My below code executed 6 times, clicked on 6 options and fetched the value from the dropdown and displaying on console. If a single listitem is missing from dropdown, its displaying 'Missing Listitem' on console. And if one of the item missing, the testcase should get failed but without stopping execution until it displays all the  listitems for all taboptions.
Here is the code:

```
public void patientDetails() throws IOException {

        for(int i=0; i<patientDetailsOptions.size();i++)  //Total 6 times loop is going to be execute as 6 tab options are in one row.
        {            
                clickDropdown.get(i).click();  //Clicking on dropdown of each taboptions

        List<WebElement> Patient_details = clickDropdown.get(i).findElements(By.xpath("//div[@id='modal-patient-detail-section']/ul[@class='patient-demographics-dropdown open']/ul/li"));  
        //Fetching list item from that dropdownand storing into Patient_details.


        //Now printing all list item of taboption one after other if, list items are not as per size should display "Missing Listitem".
        for(int k=0; k< Patient_details.size(); k++)
            {
                String toolTips = Patient_details.get(k).getText(); 
                if(!toolTips.isEmpty())
                {
                    toolTips=toolTips.replaceAll("\n", " ");
                    System.out.println(toolTips);

                }else {
                     System.err.println("Missing ListItem");
                         //Assert.assertFalse(toolTips.isEmpty());
                     softAssert.assertFalse(toolTips.isEmpty());

                       }
                    }
                 }
              }
```

My above code executed successfully with Failures:0 with one 'Missing ListItem'.
If listitmes are not as per Patient_details.size(), my code is printing ' Missing ListItem'.
And if once found 'Missing ListItems' on console it should fail the test case but should not stop the execution until it displays the listitmes for each tab options.

With "softassert.assertFalse(toolTips.isEmpty)" shouldn't stop further execution but my test case got pass, i wanted it to be fail as one listitem is missing.
Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Please add you test case where you are calling this function and declaring soft assertion object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to make it fail if **Missing ListItems** then simply use `fail` assertion.

Please use below line

```
softAssert.fail("Failing as list item is missing.");
```

**OR**

```
softAssert.assertFalse(toolTips.isEmpty);
```

**But Most important:**

You have to use this line in end (after  `patientDetails()` **OR** `For loop`) to accumulate soft assertion result.

```
softAssert.assertAll();
```

[Here](https://artoftesting.com/soft-assertion-in-testng-selenium-webdriver-java) is good example to understand soft assertion.

Comment: softAssert.fail("Failing as list item is missing.");, this has not failed my testcase. Total tests run :1, Failures:0. I want this testcase should get fail. The result should be          Total tests run :1, Failures:1.

Comment: It should fail but i am worried it this code reachable in execution. Do you getting any error too?

Comment: if writing this statement " Assert.assertFalse(toolTips.isEmpty());" instead of softAssert, its failing my testcase but no further execution. I want further execution as well.

Comment: Soft assertion never stop execution, in case of fail on assertion it will show all result after execution.

Comment: It displaying 'Missing List Item for 2nd taboption and execution get stop after printing the statement "Missing ListItem'.

Comment: Here is the problem. Edited the question.

Comment: I added immediately after softAssert  softAssert.fail("Failing as list item is missing");
      softAssert.assertAll();, it has stop the execution once found "Missing ListItem, no further execution.

Comment: @Appi It should be added in last, after for loop oR patientDetails() function in your case as it collect result. If you will add in between For loop, it will think execution is finished here

Comment: Okay, i added at after main for loop  for(int i=0; i<patientDetailsOptions.size();i++), after displayed Missing ListItem, it got failed and stop execution. And also tried after adding line to inner for loop - for(int k=0; k< Patient_details.size(); k++)., same result

Comment: Add it after patientDetails function. This is the single test case or you hv more test case. I want to say it should be last line, if you are using multiple function

Comment: it has to be used in testfile only i am trying in pageobject and then calling this method in testcase file by creating an object. When putting after public void patientDetails() throws IOException { -this statement it showing redline and saying "Syntax error on 'assertAll', Identifier expected after this token

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/206107/discussion-between-appi-and-muzzamil).